# Order balance not directly updated after payment created

Tags: commerce, 9, payment-gateways

I'm trying to figure out why my order balance isn't directly updated after I've created a payment. I'm debugging it with xDebug. This is my OnNotify function

```
$this->order = Order::load($orderId);
//isPaid = false
  if ($this->order !== NULL) {
    //create the payment, assign it to the order
    $payment = $this->createPayment($this->order, $mt);
    if ($this->order->isPaid()) { //isPaid still false instead of true
```

This is how the payment is created

```
  protected function createPayment(OrderInterface $order, $mt){
    $payment_storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('commerce_payment');
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_payment\Entity\Payment $payment */
    $payments = $payment_storage->loadByProperties(['order_id' => $this->order->id()]);
    $price = new Price(((int)$mt)/100, 'EUR');
    if (count($payments) == 0) {
      $payment = $payment_storage->create([
        'state' => 'completed',
        'amount' => $price,
        'payment_gateway' => $this->entityId,
        'order_id' => $this->order->id(),
        'remote_id' => null,
        'remote_state' => null,
        'completed' => time()
      ]);
      $payment->save();
      $this->order->save();
      return $payment;
    }
```

So if i put breakpoint, the isPaid is always false. However, if I don't use the debugger, the order balance works correctly (without the process beeing executed twice or anything...). Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Payment entity's post save function explains it:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function postSave(EntityStorageInterface $storage, $update = TRUE) {
    parent::postSave($storage, $update);

    $order = $this->getOrder();
    if ($order && $this->isCompleted()) {
      $payment_order_updater = \Drupal::service('commerce_payment.order_updater');
      $payment_order_updater->requestUpdate($order);
    }
  }
```

When a payment is saved, a request to the related order is merely requested, not initiated. At the end of the page request, when PHP is destroying the `PaymentOrderUpdater` service, that is when the updates to the relevant orders are finally processed. This is to avoid any kind of "save within a save" scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations.